# Quotient of finite, nilpotent group by Frattini subgroup is isomorphic to product of quotients of Sylow subgroups by their respective Frattini groups.

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory, direct-product, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a finite nilpotent group.

We know that $G=G_{p_1}\times G_{p_2}\times \cdots \times G_{p_r}$ where $G_{p_i}\in Syl_{p_i}(G)$, $i=1,\dots,r$.

Is the following equation right? And why?

$G/\Phi(G)=G_{p_1}/\Phi(G_{p_1})\times\cdots\times G_{p_r}/\Phi(G_{p_r})$,

where $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What's $\Phi(G)$? Frattini subgroup?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown  Yes!

Comment: The Frattini subgroup satisfies $\Phi(H_1\times H_2)=\Phi(H_1)\times\Phi(H_2)$ so then $(H_1\times H_2)/\Phi(H_1\times H_2)=H_1/\Phi(H_1)\times H_2/\Phi(H_2)$ etc.

Comment: Yes: An "n" is missing.